# Remove words containing vowels

Tags: python

I am looking output string having vowels removed.

- Input: My name is 123
- Output: my 123

I tried below code:

```
def without_vowels(sentence):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    word = sentence.split()
    for l in word:
       for k in l:
          if k in vowels:
              l = ''

without_vowels('my name 123')
```

Can anyone give me result using list compression ?

Comment: `[word for word in sentence.split() if not any(vowel in word for vowel in "aeiou")]`

Comment: Isn't 'y' a vowel in 'my'? In any event, this seems suspiciously like homework which you are foisting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What's the problem with the code? Why do you want a list comprehension? Please read the [site guidelines on asking (good) questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regex` with search chars with `'a|e|i|o|u'` with `.lower()` for words if have upper char like below:

```
>>> import re

>>> st = 'My nAmE Is 123 MUe'

>>> [s for s in st.split() if not re.search(r'a|e|i|o|u',s.lower())]
['My', '123']

>>> ' '.join(s for s in st.split() if not re.search(r'a|e|i|o|u',s.lower()))
'My 123'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it

```
def without_vowels(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    cleaned_words = [w for w in words if not any(v in w for v in vowels)]
    cleaned_string = ' '.join(cleaned_words)
    print(cleaned_string)
```

Outputs `my 123`

Answer (score 1):

```
def rem_vowel(string):

    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

    result = [letter for letter in string if letter.lower() not in vowels]

    result = ''.join(result)

    print(result)
string = "My name is 123"
rem_vowel(string)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include an explanation of the code

Answer (score 1):

import re

def rem_vowel(string):

```
return (re.sub("[aeiouAEIOU]","",string))
```

## Driver program

string = " I am uma Bhargav "

print rem_vowel(string)